# Saving the position of a Drag and drop ImageButton

Tags: java, android, database, mobile, imagebutton

Is there a way to save where a drag and drop image button was placed by the user so that the next time the app is started, the imagebutton will be in the place it was left last? I am assuming shared preferences would work, but I have heard that when the app is updated, shared preferences are forgotten so I would like to save the coordinates if possible in my database. I just have no idea how to get the coordinates I need to be able to save them. The thing I would like best is to just be able to save the x and y coordinates if possible.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue by saving the x and y coordinates as floats in my sqlite database. The coordinates are then loaded up when the app is opened back up and the imagebuttons are loaded back up at the coordinates they were left at by pulling the saved coordinates from the database.